# Can spin be used for charged particle identification?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, quantum-spin, particle-detectors

In modern particle physics experiments, identification of charged particles (pions, kaons, muons, protons, electrons) is often required. This is usually achieved with techniques based either on [time-of-flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_flight_detector), or on the energy deposit (dE/dx energy loss, [Cherenkov light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring-imaging_Cherenkov_detector), etc). All of those provide a reliable separation only in certain range of momenta.

Now, the elephant in the room: out of particles listed above, pions and kaons have spin 0 while protons, muons and electrons have spin 1/2. Can this feature be used in modern experiments to separate them?

Addition: Many experiments have a magnet, which makes me think of [Stern-Gerlach experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment), even though the effect of the track curvature in the magnetic field needs to be taken into account.
However, probably, some other implementations could be found.

Comment: A non uniform field is needed to cause the deflection due to spin. The high level description of a tracking detector implies it has a uniform field. If it can be used then there should be a detector with an appropriate field. Been looking myself. Perhaps you should add this fact to your question to help get more answers?

Answer (score 0):

> Can spin be used for charged particle identification?

Please recall what the conservation rules for each single  event studied with the detectors of high energy physics, just energy and momentum. Even though angular momentum is conserved  at the interaction point , it is not a value that can be measured per event because all the quantum mechanical effects happen below distances of a fermi. Spin is a quantum mechanical variable and to be seen macroscopically probability distributions are needed. A single evenτ is one entry in a probability distribution. In scattering a proton on a proton one cannot control at the quantum level the angular momentum per event, as can be done in diffractive experiments.

Comment: If the particle is known via normal methods then can the spin be detected? Not sure for the trackers have enough resolution but also not sure if any detecters have the non uniform magnetic field needed to detect spin. If realistically detectable then has anyone tried? I was about to post this as a question but found this post here.

Comment: To detect the spin of an individual  *charged* outgoing particle and record it per particle for each event would mean enormously complicating the experiment  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment) for very small gain in information, as the particles can be identified by other means. For a neutral particle the decay products in the high energy experiments can lead to knowledge of the parent spin.